# Hi I'm trying to add @Value("${name}") private String name; in dto field but not able to read it from application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

```
class dto{@Value("${name}")  private String name; }
```

application.properties

op.name=${OP_NAME:22-2}

//When I try to read it is returning null how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [@Value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation will only be processed on Spring-managed beans (e.g. a `@Component` annotated class).

Additionally, you would need to specify the property key in `@Value` as follows in order to match with the key defined in your property file:

```
@Value("${op.name:fallback}")
private String name;
```

Your properties file can then carry the configurable value:

```
op.name=Some Name
```